# NodeJs Express routes not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I only got `/` route to work. From what I see most problems like mine are that routers are mounted to some path like `/auth` or `/user`. Now I tested my default router that is mounted to `/` and its still not working. This is my code:

```
import indexRouter from './routes/index'
app.use('/',indexRouter);
```

and in my routes/index

```
import { Router } from 'express';
const router = Router();

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.send(true);
})

router.get('ping',(req,res)=>{
  res.send('pong')
})

export default router;
```

when I visit `/` its working, and `ping` is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please change like below.

**FROM**

```
router.get('ping',(req,res)=>{
  res.send('pong')
})
```

**TO**

> Please add / into routing url.

```
router.get('/ping',(req,res)=>{
  res.send('pong')
})
```

Comment: you can check as right answer, if this solved your problem.

Comment: It did, can you explain why would it be problem ? I'll select your answer in a few minutes when it becomes available

Comment: Please check this expressjs official site. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html.
here can you see all the route definition starts with / ?